# Django REST Framework POST data with file error (using ModelResource)

Tags: django, file, post, urllib2, django-rest-framework

I have a really big problem trying to post data with file in a Django REST Framework app. I've created a simple application by the example at djangorestframework website. So I have the urls file:

```
class MyImageResource(ModelResource):
    model = Image
```

and in urlpatters:

```
url(r'^image/$', ListOrCreateModelView.as_view(resource=MyImageResource)),
url(r'^image/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$', InstanceModelView.as_view(resource=MyImageResource)),
```

The Image model is simple:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_file_path)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Testing the REST page in browser, works perfect. Even posting data with files.

My problem is that I want to create a simple python application to post data. I've used simple urllib2, but I get 500 Internal Error or 400 Bad Request:

```
poza = open('poza.jpg', 'rb')


initial_data = (    
    {'name', 'Imagine de test REST'},
    {'description', 'Dude, this is awesome'},
    {'image', poza},
)

d = urllib.urlencode(initial_data)
r = urllib2.Request('http://localhost:8000/api/image/', data=d,
                headers={'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'})
resp = urllib2.urlopen(r)
code = resp.getcode()
data = resp.read()
```

I've tried also with MultipartPostHandler:

```
import MultipartPostHandler, urllib2, cookielib
cookies = cookielib.CookieJar()

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies),
                          MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler)

params = {
    "name":"bob",
    "description":"riviera",
    "content" : open("poza.jpg", "rb")
}

opener.open("http://localhost:8000/api/image/", params)
```

but same: 500 or 400 errors and the server (python manage.py runserver) stops with the following errors:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 64879)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 570
, in __init__
    BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 641, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 694, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in yo
ur host machine
```

If somebody have, please give me an example of posting data with files or tell me what's wrong in my posting python code. I couldn't find any more examples.

The server looks ok, I can POST data in browser. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with your code...
You should try using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) instead of urllib. It will help avoiding the urllib headaches.

Comment: Is it possible you have some sort of firewall on your machine getting in the way? re: "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look as if you are reading in the file, and are instead passing the file pointer?

Try:

```
initial_data = (    
    {'name', 'Imagine de test REST'},
    {'description', 'Dude, this is awesome'},
    {'image', poza.read()},
)
```